# Rails: image change position after being updated

Tags: html, css, position, edit

I'm building a photography website for a friend and she wants to be able to upload, edit and delete images.
Everything is ok on localhost but i've noticed that when i edit an image, it change position and become the last one. Does anyone know why is that happening or can tell me how can i sort the images from the date they have been created?

**index.html.erb:**

```
<section class='container'>
  <article id='gallery'>
    <% PreviewPicture.all.each do |preview_picture| %>
      <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="<%= preview_picture.picture.image.url(:original)%>" ><%= image_tag preview_picture.image.url(:original), :class => 'grayscale' %></a>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <%= link_to "Delete #{preview_picture.id}", preview_picture_path(:id => preview_picture.id), method: :delete %>
          <%= link_to "Edit #{preview_picture.id}", edit_preview_picture_path(:id => preview_picture.id) %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </article>
</section>

<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= link_to "Add Picture", new_preview_picture_path, :class => "add_preview_picture" %>
<% end %>
```

**gallery.css:**

```
section.container {
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 69%;
}

img.grayscale{ 
  margin: 1.5px 0px;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);  /* For Webkit browsers */
  filter: gray;  /* For IE 6 - 9 */
}

img.grayscale:hover{ 
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  filter: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to create a scope or a class method on the `PreviewPicture` model that sorts the pictures by date created or updated.

```
class PreviewPicture < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.by_date
       order(created_at: :desc) // or order(updated_at: :desc)
    end
end
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
PreviewPicture.by_date.each
```

It's good practice to set this in the controller, so in your view's corresponding PreviewPictureController action:

```
@preview_pictures = PreviewPicture.by_date
```

And then iterate through the `@preview_pictures` instance variable in your view.

Comment: It wasn't me who put the downvote.. I just saw your answer! It looks good, i'm going to try it know. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Ah, wasn't suggesting it was you :)  Just curious.  Have a good one!